# Get directory path in Array of Objects from directory path as string

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Been searching SO posts, nothing answers this for me yet.

I have an Array of folders like such :

```
[{
"name": "home",
"folders": [{
    "name": "New Folder",
    "folders": [{
        "name": "53w5r",
        "folders": [{
            "name": "test",
            "folders": []
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "public folder",
    "folders": [{
        "name": "cold",
        "folders": []
    }, {
        "name": "hot",
        "folders": []
    }]
}, {
    "name": "My Folder",
    "folders": []
}]
```

}]

I need to find search this array using a path string such as the following :

```
"home,New Folder,53w5r,test"
```

I'm searching for that folder, so a findFolder method would take the string above and return the folder objects in the "test" folder .

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you rephrase it?

Comment: Shouldn't it technically be `"home,New Folder,53w5r,test"`?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you..  Edited.

Comment: @Jason I have updated my answer. It now shows the correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your comma-separated path will always be valid, you can use this simple method for traversing the data:

```js
var str = "home,New Folder,53w5r,test";
var data = [{
  "name": "home",
  "folders": [{
    "name": "New Folder",
    "folders": [{
      "name": "53w5r",
      "folders": [{
        "name": "test",
        "folders": []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "public folder",
    "folders": [{
      "name": "cold",
      "folders": []
    }, {
      "name": "hot",
      "folders": []
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "My Folder",
    "folders": []
  }]
}];

var folderNames = str.split(",");
var result = folderNames.reduce((results, folderName, index) => {
  var currFolder = results.find(folder => folder.name === folderName);
  // if last folder, return entire folder, otherwise return currFolder.folders
  return index === folderNames.length-1 ? currFolder : currFolder.folders;
}, data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation without reduce, it will return null if the directory wasn't found.

```js
const dirSeperator = ",";

function findDir(path, dirs) {
  var parts = path.split(dirSeperator);

  if (parts && parts.length > 0) {
    var n = parts[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
      if (dirs[i].name === n) {
        if (parts.length > 1)
          return findDir(path.replace(n + dirSeperator, ''), dirs[i].folders)
        else if (parts.length == 1)
          return dirs[i]
      }
    }

    return null;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

var dirs = [{
    "name": "Test",
    "folders": [{
      "name": "Test2",
      "folders": [{
          "name": "test 3",
          "folders": []
        },
        {
          "name": "test 3",
          "folders": []
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "Main",
    "folders": [{
      "name": "Test2",
      "folders": [{
          "name": "test 3",
          "folders": []
        },
        {
          "name": "test 3",
          "folders": []
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
];
const testcase = "Test,Test2,test 3";
console.log('Searching for', testcase, ' in ', dirs)
console.log(findDir(testcase, dirs))
```

Comment: @Ivan pft, it was hard to write so it should be equally hard to read ;) Recursion is always fun

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a 2 line solution:**

You can use the [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/find) method to search for a folder on a level:

```
(folder, name) => folder.folders.find(e => e.name == name);
```

Then I have written a recursive function that will look up the folders for each element of the provided path. It uses [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/reduce) to keep track of the parent folder (`acc`). At the end of the loop it returns the last folder array (the one at the end of the path).

```
path.split(',').reduce((acc, curr) => find(acc, curr), {folders:folders});
```

Here's a quick demo:

```js
const find = (folder, name) => folder.folders.find(e => e.name == name);

const getFolders = path => path.split(',').reduce((acc, curr) => find(acc, curr), {folders:folders});

console.log(
  getFolders('home,New Folder,53w5r,test')
);
```

```html
<script>
const folders = [{
  "name": "home",
  "folders": [{
    "name": "New Folder",
    "folders": [{
      "name": "53w5r",
      "folders": [{
        "name": "test",
        "folders": []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "public folder",
    "folders": [{
      "name": "cold",
      "folders": []
    }, {
      "name": "hot",
      "folders": []
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "My Folder",
    "folders": []
  }]
}]
</script>
```

Comment: OP wants the folder object itself at the end, not the contents on the `folders` array (since it will likely be empty, and it's not overly helpful if those aren't what you're looking for). This is also just a less-verbose but less-readable version of my answer that I posted.

Comment: `just a less-verbose but less-readable version of my answer`, that's nice! I love Stack Overflow's users. You need some practice to read this code I'll give you that but I don't think is not readable. I have used functions to separate different tasks. `acc` and `curr` don't need other names. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Ivan Part of SO is being helping other people understand. Jamming everything on to a single line may show your JS prowess, but to most people who are asking the questions, it is just jargon. A perfect example is one-lining `.reduce()`. It takes extra time to figure out what exactly is being returned, because the comma toward the end can be the comma operator, or it can be separating parameters. It's not exactly clear, and you have to spend extra time combing the rest of the code to ensure how the comma is being used.

Comment: @Ivan It is important to keep in mind that source code is not written for the computer. We write source code for the developer. Sometimes (not always) verbosity is a *good* thing. Your computer will take care of stripping whitespace, minifying, and obfuscating, and interpreting the code.

Comment: @mhodges Fair enough, you've made your point and I agree. Elegant code is nice though. Also, I didn't enjoy the way you handled the discussion... Anyway